# Using mouse to navigate to type using YouCompleteMe plugin

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-you-complete-me, mouse

I'm trying to map ctrl+click event to generic navigation for java types using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) plugin. There's plugin command to do that: `:YcmCompleter GoTo` it navigates to "most sensible" place for type under cursor: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#the-goto-subcommand:

> This command tries to perform the "most sensible" GoTo operation it can

This is my `.vim/ftplugin/java.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <C-LeftMouse> :YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>
```

It's working but with one exception: it doesn't change cursor position before performing `GoTo` command, e.g. if the cursor is located on one type and I'm clicking another type, it will open first type. It seems that I'm doing something wrong here. I need first move cursor to clicking position and then execute the command, or maybe I'm doing something wrong here and vim has another way to implement such feature. How to implement it correctly?

Comment: Would something like `nnoremap <buffer> <C-LeftMouse> :norm! <LeftMouse><CR>:YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>` work? I didn't test but the idea is to make your mapping actually click the mouse and then use the `YcmCompleter` command.

Comment: @statox no, it doesn't. `:norm! \<LeftMouse\>` doesn't change the word under cursor.

Comment: Well is was just a supposition too bad it didn't work... But I'm sure someone on here will be able to help you :)